# How to receive emails from client using PHPMailer instead of sending them in PHP?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I've tried the `mail()` function in PHP, and it won't work, but I've installed the PHPMailer library using composer, and It worked perfectly while sending emails to myself.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer();


//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'myEmail@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'MyPassword';                               //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`



// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";


//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('email@gmail.com', '');
$mail->addAddress('someone@gmail.com', '');     //Add a recipient

// Message
$mail->Subject = 'some subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Some Content';

// Sending
$mail->send();
?>
```

But, actually, my goal was to make people able to send me messages via a contact form on my project's contact page.

Basically, we'll have to provide a password here from the sender? and that's not what I want, I just want to receive messages from users, not to send them.

So, How could I perform this logic?

Comment: Set `Reply-To` to the user's address, if you want the recipient of the mail that was sent from your address (the one that matches the SMTP account) to be able to answer to the user with a single click within their mail client. DO NOT try to "fake" a different `From` address, that's only going to lead to trouble with spam filters.

Comment: Base your code on [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) which demonstrates the right way to handle this.

Comment: @CBroe, I can't thank you enough, this seems like solved my problem with some tweaks, thanks for taking the time to pay attention to my problem, really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Synchro, Great resource, Synchro, Thank you so much, I've saved it for further tweaks on my contact form, that was very helpful 3>